# создание формы для добавления данных в таблицу

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc, ruby

Есть метки задач с задачами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На главной странице нужно создать форму для добавления **задач**, причем нужно иметь возможность выбрать **метку** для этой задачи. В итоге должно получиться что-то типа такого.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для контроллера для добавления задачи

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_todo_list
def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.create(todo_item_params)
    if @todo_item.save
        redirect_to @todo_list
    end
end

def destroy 
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    if @todo_item.destroy
        flash[:success] = "Задача была удалена!"
    else 
        flash[:error] = "Задача не была удалена, повторите попытку снова!"
    end
    redirect_to @todo_list
end


private

def set_todo_list
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
end

def todo_item_params
    params[:todo_item].permit(:text)
end
end
```

Сколько я бы не мучился, не получается это сделать, от слова совсем, буду очень рад любой помощи.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, код самой удачной попытки, моделей и формы. И объясните более подробно, что именно не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно сам ответ, спустя несколько часов:)

```
     <div class="form-box">
        <div class="form-box-wrapper">
          <%= form_for :todo, url: todos_path do |form| %>
            <%= form.text_field :text, placeholder: 'Название задачи' %>
            <%= form.select(:project_id, Project.all.collect{|p| [ p.title, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'None'}) %>
            <br>
            <%= form.submit %>
            <a href="/" id="candel_button" class="cansel">ОТМЕНА</a>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
```